# Using NSDate in While loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to get the current date using [NSDate date] in a While Loop. I accomplish this by doing like this:

```
while (interval > 0.0) {

    NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];  
    currentDate =  [NSDate date];  
    interval = (float) [newDate timeIntervalSinceDate: currentDate] / 60;  
    [currentDate release];
}
```

I dont know why is the Memory leaks shows that there is a great amount of memory is leaked. Kindly guide me that what is the right way to accomplish my task.

Comment: You have several good answers here; Konstantin points out your bug. Andrei points out the problem with generating large numbers of objects in a loop without draining the autorelease pool. But you should also evaluate your code and make sure you really mean to do this. In the code above, you're busy waiting, which means that you're eating a lot of battery. There are much less power-intensive ways to wait. The easiest is NSTimer. Perhaps this is simplified code to show a point, but generating "now" objects in a loop is probably wrong.

Comment: @Rob: I know but do you think that NSTimer will work with PerformSelectorInBackground ??

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just because you're running "in the background" doesn't mean you can busy-wait. It eats the same amount of CPU on any thread. What problem are you solving here? NSTimer works on any thread that processes its run loop.

Comment: as far as my research on background thereading is concerned, i never see a single post who approved that NSTimer will work in background thread, it only works on Main thread that is why i am trying to accomplish it with a simple while loop. If you think there is another way to accomplish this loop without using While and NSTimer then kindly share it with us.

Comment: NSTimers work on any thread that processes its runloop. You can read "Starting the Run Loop" in the Threading Programming Guide for more information on how to manage runloops on background threads to avoid draining your battery: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html. You can also block waiting for things using GCD and operation queues. See Concurrency Programming Guide. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html.'

Comment: Finally, if you just want your thread to wait until such-and-such a time, you can easily do that with NSThread sleepUntilDate: or sleepForTimeInterval:. Cocoa is rich in ways to wait for something without polling.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this info Rob. It would be a great help in future for me..! Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that you are leaking per se but that you are running in a while loop.

The auto released dates are growing in the autorelease pool because the pool only empties in the idle time on the run loop.

One solution is to create a local autorelease pool within the scope of the while

```
  while (foo) {
      NSAutoreleasePool *aPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc ] init];
      NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
      // other computational foo
      [aPool release]
  }
```

When you release the pool in the local scope it will immediately drop the autoreleased date you requested.

Comment: No worries. Had to fix a shred of code that did this very thing. It was a run wait loop, so we were blowing more and more memory waiting for a thread to conclude.

Comment: yeah right. In my case I can also use sleepForTimeInterval type property bcoz i just want to make wait for some time and then do the remaining task.

Answer (score 6):

In line `NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];` you create a new object, which you should release. In line `currentDate = [NSDate date];` you do not release an old object, you only make a pointer to point to another object. In line `[currentDate release];` you release an object created on the second line of a loop, which may cause an error (that object is marked as autorelease one and iOS will clean it for you). You should rewrite your code like:

```
while (interval > 0.0) {
      NSDate *currentDate =  [NSDate date];
      interval = (float) [newDate timeIntervalSinceDate: currentDate] / 60;
}
```

Comment: but sir i double checked the same code with Leaks Performance tool which shows that the memory is consuming continously :(

Comment: @Wasim: I can state that the code I wrote has no memory leaks. Maybe the problem is nearby, but it is certainly not here.

Comment: ok sir i will check it again and will get back to you shortly. Thanks a lot for your prompt response :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the first line `NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];`. You can directly assign the *[NSDate date]* to *currentDate*.

```
NSDate *currentDate =  nil;

while (interval > 0.0) {

    currentDate =  [NSDate date];
    interval = (float) [newDate timeIntervalSinceDate: currentDate] / 60;
}
```

Comment: then how will i release it? I read somewhere that NSDate object has no need to be released but when i see Leaks Performance Tool, it shows clearly that a huge amount of memory is leaking. Kindly guide me with this also.

Comment: `[NSDate date];` returns an autoreleased object. So you've no need to release the *currentDate* in my example.

Comment: still the same result, memory is leaking continuously. If i comment the NSDate object then memory leakage is stopped, so its enough cleared that the reason of leakage is the same object.

Comment: @Wasim, I am not sure how the leak occurs. But try my updated answer. It may solve your problem.

Comment: @Wasim, @Simon: the code written by Simon certainly has no memory leaks.

Comment: i am also amazed :( but i will test the updated code and will let you know in some minutes. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Simon, @Konstantin: I think i am doing something wrong as both of your given codes didnt worked. Kindly tell me one thing also that can i put a while loop in ApplicationDidEnterBackground Delegate?