# For Loop for NSDate

Tags: ios4, for-loop, nsdate, ios5

I'm trying to create a for loop with NSDates, so that the loop would increment by 1 day each cycle of the for loop...

```
NSDate *startDate = datePicker.date;
NSDate *endDate = datePicker2.date;

for (int i = startDate; i < endDate; i++) 
{

}
```

The build fails because of me jamming a NSDate where the int is...
I also tried...

```
NSDate *startDate = datePicker.date;
NSDate *endDate = datePicker2.date;

for (NSDate *i = startDate; i < endDate; i++) 
{

}
```

That did not build either. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (NSDate *date = [startDate copy]; [date compare: endDate] < 0; date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:24 * 60 * 60] ) 
    {
        NSLog( @"%@ in [%@,%@]", date, startDate, endDate );
    }
```

[Using NSDate in While loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305287/using-nsdate-in-while-loop)